# How to show clicked text value on search input box using Angularjs Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have google like text box for search and list of text value shown beneath it. I want to click on any of text value [button] and show the selected text value to shown in search box.

How can I do it?

Comment: please share your code what you have tried so far, it will be easy for everyone to answer your question

Answer (score -1):

You can simply assign that value to the modal of that text box on the click event of button.

Can tell you better if you can post your code as well.